# VS2017 Debugger Breakpoints not working with locally run Azure Function

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I've used Visual Studio 2017 to create a queue triggered Azure Function. All that the default generated code does is write a message to the log. The code works, but if you set a breakpoint on it, it is ignored by the debugger.

I have same problem with another queue triggered function that has more complex code, but I created this one as a very simple test case.

What do you have to do to get debug breakpoints to work on this type of project?

Comment: Debugging should just work when you run from F5. Is that what you are trying?

Comment: I agree that it should, but it doesn't.  I just found the answer [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166316/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbol.html) which is right click the project, go to PROPERTIES->Build and click the ADVANCED button, then change debugging info from "Portable" to "Full"

Answer (score 3):

Answer was found [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166316/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbol.html) which is:
(1) right click your project and go to properties page
(2) select "Build" on left
(3) click "Advanced..." button
(4) change "Debugging information" to "Full"

Answer (score 0):

As stupid as it sounds, I managed to make it work by unchecking the option

```
Automatically close the console when debugging stops
```

in Tools > Options > Debugging > General